# Android composite primary key?

Tags: android, composite-primary-key

Can anyone tell me how to declare a composite primary key in Android 1.6 which includes an autoincrement _id column? I'm not sure of the syntax. I've ended up just enforcing it in Java when I try to add values (where registrationNumber + date has to be unique in the table):

```
            Cursor fuelUpsCursor = getFuelUps(registrationNumber, date);
        if(!fuelUpsCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            //add registrationNumber and date
        }
```

I don't really need the _id column but it can make life tricky if tables don't have one.

Cheers,
Barry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question does not make much sense. Your subject line asks for a "composite foreign key", your first sentence asks for a "composite primary key" with an `AUTOINCREMENT` that your sample code then ignores.

I am going to interpret your question this way: You want an `_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` column in your table to be able to use Android's `CursorAdapter`, but you want to also make sure that the combination of two other columns is unique.

In that case, I think that you want to use a `UNIQUE` constraint:

- [Multiple Unique Columns in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604319/multiple-unique-columns-in-sqllite)
- [SQLite table constraint - unique on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701877/sqlite-table-constraint-unique-on-multiple-columns)
- http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Apologies - I changed my mind about primary vs foreign key after I wrote the title. I've changed it now. Thanks for your reply - UNIQUE was indeed correct -    `<code>`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + FUEL_USE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + REGISTRATION_NO_COLUMN + " TEXT, " + DATE_TIME_COLUMN + " TEXT, UNIQUE (" + REGISTRATION_NO_COLUMN + ", " + DATE_TIME_COLUMN + "));");`<code>`